# Forcing, missing condition in front of the forcing symbol, meaning

Tags: notation, set-theory, forcing

What it means in the forcing theoretic contex this symbol

$\Vdash \psi$

*without* condition $p$
in front of it? How do I make sense of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the weakest condition forces the statement. (Either maximum or minimum, depending on your convention.)

Equivalently, every condition forces the statement.